# how to set a condition with a variable as a parameter in a function?

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, scope

I made a function, but i need to call it using a specific condition under a certain circumstance, the only problem is the variable i need to check is in the function i created.

here is an example of what i am trying to do:

```
        //this works since nothing is out of scope
        function thisWorks(condition) {
            if (condition) {
                console.log("works");
                alert("works");
            }
        }
        thisWorks(3 < 2);
        //this wont work since the x var is out of scope
        function howDoIDoThis(condition) {
            let x = 3;
            if (condition) {
                console.log("i dont know how to do this");
            }
        }

        howDoIDoThis(x === 3);
```

is there a way i can reference the x variable? I know in this example i can easily just move the  x out, but for the thing i am actually trying to do, the x needs to stay inside the function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't care about the names of variables inside another function.

Instead, pass a callback function that receives the variable as a parameter, and calculates the condition.

```js
function howDoIDoThis(condition_function) {
  let x = 3;
  if (condition_function(x)) {
    console.log("The condition is true");
  } else {
    console.log("The condition is false");
  }
}

howDoIDoThis(n => n == 3);
howDoIDoThis(z => z == 2);
```

Comment: Awesome, that works. very interesting how its done. thank you :)